# CSS: avoid skipping a row when moving cursor down table

Tags: javascript, html, css

When cells hide overflow and show it on hover if:

a) you are moving mouse cursor down descending rows

AND

b)the difference in height of the overflow of the cell you are on and the one you are going to is greater than the total height of overflow of the cell you are moving over on.

You will skip at least one row!

Html:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
<table class="superResponsive">
    <thead>
 </tr>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>TEST</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>LAST</th>
    </tr>  
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td><div class="content">
                <p>Some DataSome DataSome DataSome Data</p>
                <p>Some DataSome DataSome DataSome Data</p>
                <p>Some DataSome DataSome DataSome Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">

           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">

            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </td>
           </div> <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">

           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
        </tr>          <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td><div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">

           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">

            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">

           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </td>
           </div> <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">

           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
        </tr>          <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td><div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">

           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">

            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </td>
           </div> <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">

           </div> </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p>Some Data</p>
            </div></td>
        </tr>   

    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .superResponsive{
  width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.superResponsive td, .superResponsive th{

   width:200px;


   min-height:30px;
   height:30px;
   min-height:30px;

   border:1px solid black;
   vertical-align: top;

}

.content{
   overflow: hidden;
  width:200px;

   min-height:30px;
   height:30px;
   min-height:30px;

}

.superResponsive td:hover .content{
    background:lightGrey;

    overflow: visible;
    height:auto;
    color:yellow;


}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/coolcatDev/r190r8hn/1/

Go to the column named "TEST" and try to go with the cursor from the cell of row 1 to the one on row 2 of the column "TEST"

Suggestions to avoid this behaviour without sacrificing the idea of single line rows that display all content on hover.

Comment: Please comment why down vote, so I can improve my question. This little detail is a huge flaw in a table of mine and is really being a challenge to solve for me

Comment: Attempting to trick the system by formatting random text as code instead of providing the code in question itself will attract downvoters. And close votes.

Comment: The code provided in my fiddle example is exactly the issue I am dealing with! How is that tricking the system, not sure I understand why you are saying reproducing the issue in fiddle is a bad thing

Comment: Ok understand now. still don't understand the need of duplicating the code when fiddle is provided. P.S. didn't notice the "Links to jsfiddle..." message, thanks for pointing out, won't trick again

Comment: @AlExTsm We don't duplicate code due so that your question will be here, even if Jsfiddle happens to go down - plus it makes it easier for the people who are helping you by answering your question.

Comment: Sure, what ever is preferred. I wasn't clear how to describe the issue, therefor I neither was able to find anything on the topic in question searching on google. Is there any article or question anyone can point out to go around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r190r8hn/9/).
Major change I had made was adding `position: absolute`

```
.superResponsive td:hover .content{
    background: black none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: yellow;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

It's not perfect, but it's better than what you have.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried the same but didn't know how to go around the offset of the content when the table is scrolled. Don't know how to make the content stay attached to its parent cell when scrolled X or Y

Comment: Your solution but with position:absolute is perfect! thanks

Comment: @AlExTsm I'll edit answer then, glad it helped :).
If answer suits your needs, please mark it as correct.